# How to remove a property from an object?

Tags: javascript

Currently an event is set on `checkboxes`, and `event.target` gives me the `status (checked = true/false)` of checkbox which is clicked.

I am maintaining an object which keeps the track on all the selected checkboxes

```
var selectedMap  = {};

if(event.target == true){
    var key = event.target.id;
    var val = event.target.name;
    selectedMap[key] = val;
}
```

and I want to remove the element from the map which is unselected

```
else if(event.target == false){
  selectedMap.remove(event.target.id);
}
```

when I run this it gives me error in `Firebug` : `selectedMap.remove is not a function`

So my question is ***How can I remove the element when the checkbox is unselected ?***

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a property from a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Using `delete`:

```
delete selectedMap[event.target.id];
```

You're setting the value incorrectly, though. Here's the correct way:

```
if(event.target == true){
    var key = event.target.id;   // <== No quotes
    var val = event.target.name; // <== Here either
    selectedMap[key] = val;
}
```

In fact, you could:

```
if(event.target == true){
    selectedMap[event.target.id] = event.target.name;
}
```

Getting the event target stuff out of the way, it's easier to envision this with simple strings:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = "value of foo";
alert(obj.foo);    // alerts "value of foo" without the quotes
alert(obj["foo"]); // ALSO alerts "value of foo" without the quotes, dotted notation with a literal and bracketed notation with a string are equivalent
delete obj.foo;    // Deletes the `foo` property from the object entirely
delete obj["foo"]; // Also deletes the `foo` property from the object entirely
var x = "foo";
delete obj[x];     // ALSO deeltes the `foo` property
```

When using a plain object like this, I always use a prefix on my keys to avoid issues. (For instance, what would happen if your target element's ID was "toString"? The object already has an [inherited] property called "toString" and things would get Very Weird Very Quickly.)

So for me, I do this:

```
if(event.target == true){
    selectedMap["prefix" + event.target.id] = event.target.name;
}
```

...and of course:

```
delete selectedMap["prefix" + event.target.id];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485127/how-to-delete-unset-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object just incase u want second thought on delete

Comment: @MrigeshRajShrestha: Except that the accepted answer there is wrong.

Comment: i pulled it easily with splice; dunno what happened there.. u got jsfiddle for the issue??

Comment: @MrigeshRajShrestha: `splice` is for dealing with properties classed as *array indexes* (see [§15.4 of the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4) for which properties are classed that way). I don't know what you mean by "u got jsfiddle for the issue?". If you mean the error I pointed out in the accepted answer there, look again at my comment; there's a link to a jsbin post (jsbin is like jsfiddle) showing how it's wrong.

Comment: @TJ Crowder jsfiddle.net is a web app that allows online storage and execution of your script. good in case you want your scripts debugged by others without sharing whole info.. check that site; its awesome

Comment: @MrigeshRajShrestha: I'm familiar with jsfiddle.net (and jsbin.com, and codepen.io). That wasn't the part of the sentence that was unclear to me. Re-read the comment.

Answer (score 6):

What you have is an object and not an array (although an array is an object). You declare an object literal with `{}` whereas an array literal is declared with `[]`.

You can use `delete` to remove an object property like so

```
delete selectedMap[event.target.id];
```