# How to remove object from inside .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove a property from an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178123/how-to-remove-a-property-from-an-object)

I am comparing two JSON objects and then deleting the old items from a list with this code:

```
dangerousPeople = ({1:{title:"Jackie Chan", user:"Jackie"}, 2:{title:"Chuck Norris", user:"Chuck"}, 3:{title:"Britney spears", user:"Britney"}});
newDangerousPeople = ({1:{title:"Jackie Chan", user:"Jackie"}, 3:{title:"Britney spears", user:"Britney"}});

$.each(dangerousPeople, function(index)
{
    if(!newDangerousPeople[index]){

         $('#dangerousPeople #id'+index).slideUp("normal", function() { $(this).remove(); } );

         delete dangerousPeople.index;
    }
});
```

The part of the script that slidesup the element works, but deleting the element from the object I can't make it work.

I tried with `delete dangerousPeople.index` but doesn't work, also tried delete `$(this)` but no luck either.

So how should I remove the element from itself?

Comment: Objects need string keys. I think your outer-most objects should in fact be arrays. In addition, `.index` looks for a key named `"index"` -- you want `[index]` element access notation.

Comment: `delete dangerousPeople[index]`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: All keys are converted to strings anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
...

delete dangerousPeople[ index ];

...
```

Comment: `index` is not an object, it's a variable holding a numeric string.

Comment: In this case it's a primitive value. A string *can* be an object if you create it with `new String(...)`. Besides, it does not matter what value `index` contains. The point is that it is a variable and if you want to use a variable's value as property, you have to use bracket notation.

Comment: @FelixKling: In C++, primitives are objects too, objects simply being regions of memory. Is this not the case in JS?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, of course primitives are also kept in memory, but but they are not objects (as in they inherit from `Object`). Simple example: `var foo = "42"; foo.bar = "bar"; alert(foo.bar);`. You cannot add properties to primitive values because they are not objects. Other languages like (as it seems) C++ and Java work differently.

Comment: @FelixKling: OK - just didn't fancy looking up the definition of "object" in the rat's nest that is the ECMA spec.